# Не могу понять как выровнять элементы по одной линии

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="wrapper">
            <header class="header">`введите сюда код`
                <div class="header__container">
                    <div class="_container">
                        <div class="header__logo">
                            <a href="#" class=""><img src="img/pl.png"alt=""></a> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="header__menu">
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/menu.png" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    
.wrapper{
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100%;
}

._container{
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 50;
}

.header__container{
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.header__menu a{
  display: block;
}

.header__logo{
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.header__menu{
  margin: 0 0 0 1073px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.header__menu{
  margin: 0 0 0 1073px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

display: inline-flex; в .header__menu {} решит Вашу проблему.

Comment: Спасибо Вам!!!!